# Using git with localhost and VPS

Tags: git

Thats what I did for testing on VPS:

```
mkdir git-test && cd git-test
touch test.html
git init
git add test.html
```

On my PC localhost I tried to clone VPS-repository with TortoiseGIT, but only .git files were created without test.html. Where is my mistake?

I'm Trying to set up git, but totally stucked with it.

My simple scheme is: editing code of web-application on localhost and push changes to VPS. No extra branches and no bare repositories.

Can anyone explain me step by step, how should I do this? Edit file and just commit and push it? Will files on VPS update automatically? Do I need to type any git commands on VPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to (re-)read the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/doc) carefuly, these are the basics of GIT.

Basically, for now, you've created an empty repository and added 1 empty file.
BUT... this modification (add a file) has not been committed yet! That's why it doesn't appear on your PC when you clone the repo.

I'm using GIT for the same puprose : I edit/test code on a raspberryPi on my local network, and push changes to a server when they are validated. Here is the work flow.

The repository is created in  /home/me/gitrepos on the server. This is the 'origin' remote, and the 'master' branch.

I cloned the repo on my PC and in the directory on my webserver on the server (/var/www/...).

On my PC : edit code and push change to the repo :

```
<<Edit code>>
git add ... # if I added new files
git commit -a # commit changes to the branch
git push origin master # commit changes from my local branch to the original branch (the server)
```

On my server : pull changes from the repo and update the web application

```
cd /var/www/...
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just figured out, how to get files from remote server. I didnt make commit-that was my mistake. Now I get it.

Comment: `git pull origin master` returns `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository; fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. Tried `git add origin username@host:/var/www/public/git-test/.git` and it seems to work. Is it correct? Is there a way to add local repository as `origin`?

Comment: In my case, the repository is not in the same directory than the web server directory. That's why I needed to clone the GIT repo into the webserver directory. In your case, it seems that the repo is in the webserver directory, so, you didn't clone the repo, and there is no remote. You can add [remote manually](http://gitref.org/remotes/). Anyway, I'm not a GIT expert, perhaps someone else will be able to give you better explainations.