# Git pull origin master issues and local repository

Tags: git, git-pull

Running

```
git pull origin master
```

outputs

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

I've tried running

```
git remote add origin username@host:/var/www/public/git-test/.git
git pull origin master
```

and it seemed to work, but it output `Already up-to-date` and the file was not updated; committing and pushing from my localhost was successfull, though.

The `.git` files and the file I am trying to update are in the same directory and I have no bare repository, if that matters.

Why wasn't the file updated?
Am I doing `git remote add origin` correctly? Is there a way to add this repository as local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in [git force push current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152607/git-force-push-current-working-directory).

> - manually perform a git checkout -f to update the working dir
> - make a git post-receive hook to do it automatically.

To add local repository to git:

`git add remote origin /var/www/public/git/test`

Answer (score 0):

when adding a remote, don't put the ".git" directory in the url. Add you remote origin like this:

```
git remote add origin username@host:/var/www/public/git-test/
```

Comment: Ok, I get it. After that and again `git pull origin master` the file on the server was still not updated.

Comment: if with "server" you mean your remote origin; then you need to use git push, and not git pull

Comment: I edit files on my localhost, commiting and pushing them to VPS/server. The .git files editable files are in the /var/www/public/git-test/ directory. After commit and push on localhost, I need to update files on VPS.

Comment: you seem not to be using the correct terminology... you commit locally (on localhost). When you push, that is probably to VPS. That should work; what errors do you get.

Comment: This was my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634489/using-git-with-localhost-and-vps. I receive no errors, the file just does not update. I get Already up-to-date and thats all.